# Future perfect auxiliary forms

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, future-tense

‎Let today be monday.

1.We will have finished the work by Friday.

2.We would have finished the work by Friday.

3.We can have finished the work by Friday.

4.We could have finished the work by Friday.

5.We shall have finished the work by Friday.

6.We should have finished the work by Friday.

7.We may have finished the work by Friday.

8.We might have finished the work by Friday.

9.We must have finished the work by Friday.

I want to know all of the sentences can be used to describe future perfect expectation.

Comment: Your question is not very clear: one confusing part is **the all**. Also, what do you mean by **expectation**? Could you please  explain what you want to know in more detail?

Comment: @JavaLatte about expectation; it means I want to know that those verb forms can be used to describe the possibility of their work to be done by the time.